# How to display two elements per row with each div fitting its content in a flex container?

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, responsive-design

I have a container with multiple items, and I'm trying to achieve a layout where two items are displayed per row. Additionally, I want each item's div to fit its content without any extra space. Here's the structure of my HTML:

https://jsfiddle.net/x8jqnv7o/61/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    ITEM 1
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    ITEM 2
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    ITEM 333333333333333333
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    ITEM 4
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    ITEM 5
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS I'm currently using:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

With the above CSS, I am able to display two items per row, but the divs have a fixed width of 50%. Instead, I want each item's div to adjust its width to fit its content.

[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bX9m1.png)

How can I modify my CSS to achieve this? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

PS : The list of items in my container is dynamic and generated based on a list of strings. The number of items can vary, and each item's content will be determined by the corresponding string in the list.

Comment: looks like a typical float job, not flex. https://jsfiddle.net/4yxf2znq/

Answer (score -1):

When using flexbox, it is recommended to use flex-grow flex-shrink and flex-basis properties over width:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  // flex: 0 0 50%; This is equivalent to above 3 lines
}
```